# Android: Edit text validation for Currency

Tags: android, filter

I have a Edit-text in which user can enter amount, I want few limitations on Edit-text

1. Amount can not be greater than 100000
2. User enter amount up to two decimal places like 99999.50

**-EDITED- Solved**

How do I achieve this, do I have to create a `filter` or I can achieve it using `Regular Expression` in `myEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() ...`

```
myAmountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              if(amount!=null && amount.length()>=1 ){
                if(amount.contains(".")){
                    int indexOFdec =  amount.indexOf(".");

                    if(indexOFdec >=0) {
                       if(amount.substring(indexOFdec).length() >3){
                           amount = amount.substring(0, amount.length()-1);
                           myAmountEditText.setText(amount);
                           myAmountEditText.setSelection(myAmountEditText.getText().length());
                       }
                    }
                }

                Double a = Double.parseDouble(amount.toString());

                if(a>0 && a<100000.00){
                    //my stuff
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "amount greater than 100000", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        String strEnteredVal = edittext.getText().toString();

        if(!strEnteredVal.equals("")){
        int num=Integer.parseInt(strEnteredVal);
        if(num<100000){
         edittext.setText(""+num);
        }else{
         edittext.setText("");
        }
    }

});
```

I think we can work for that like this:

```
String str = editText.getText().toString();

    int indexOFdec =  str.indexOf(".");

    if(indexOFdec >=0) {
       if(str.substring(indexOFdec).length() >2)
       {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Print a message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return;
       }
    }
```

Comment: what about restricting user to two decimal places

Comment: helped you...??@SyedZahidAli

Comment: I am checking. i'll get back to you soon

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in your xml code. In xml where you specify the E**ditText** put this two tag inside that

```
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:maxLength="7"
```

Now use this code to notify user that they can put more than 2 digit after decimal.

```
        txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               String str = txt1.getText().toString();

                int indexOFdec =  str.indexOf(".");

                if(indexOFdec >=0) {
                   if(str.substring(indexOFdec).length() >3)
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "put Only 2 digit after decimal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       return;
                   }else{
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

        }
    });
}
```

It will work.

Comment: if I want to write 99999.51 text will stop at 99999.5

Comment: and 100000 is 6 digit amount

Comment: how would I cope with 4.333 this situation